# How do I quickly checkout a branch with a large name without using the mouse?

Tags: git

Well pretty simple. Imagine this scenario:

```
[user@home repo]$ git branch

* branch-im-currently-working-on
  long-branch-name-i-want-to-checkout-without-using-my-mouse
  long-branch-name-i-dont-want-to-checkout
  .. more-branches-with-similar-names
[user@home repo]$ git checkout now-i-have-to-type-a-lot-or-use-the-mouse
```

Any way around this? A neat solution would be if I could checkout by number, like `git checkout 1` to checkout the 1st one in the list.

I can use `tab` but if I have 20 branches all with similar names I end up having to tab like a madman and it ends up being slower than just picking up the mouse, which is a pain.

**EDIT:** I see this question isn't particularly popular so I'm just going to resolve it by trying to use shorter branch name aliases / having less local branches.

Comment: There's nothing like what you're after (`git checkout 1`) because nobody needs it, and typing `git branch`, scanning a list and finding the numeric alias of a branch that you already know the name of isn't a great workflow. Use tab completion. This is a solved problem. If you figure out tab completion, that skill carries over to virtually every other command. If you find your having to hit tab a lot, get better at naming your branches.

Comment: @meagar I appreciate your response but I've clearly stated in the question that tab completion is slower than using the mouse. I'm not sure how I can make this question more concise. I want a solution that is *quicker* than using the mouse, not slower.

Comment: My point is that it's not slower. It's you who are slower at using it. The answer is to get better at using the accepted solution, not to reject it out of hand.

Comment: @meagar, well you're either mistaken or you haven't explained why that is the case. Suppose you have 10 branches, with the names `some/branch/one/two`, `some/other/branch/one/two`, `some/branch/two/one`, etc. If you have enough of these you would need to type a letter *and* press tab up to 5 times. If that is quicker than picking up the mouse then *you* need to learn to pick up the mouse faster...

Comment: That's well-covered by the last part of my comment: Get better at naming your branches. You're basically arguing against tab completion because you can invent a worst-case scenario that you should never actually encounter in practice. My current repo has 218 branches. I seldom have to hit tab more than once.

Comment: @meagar that's probably a good answer to this question.

Comment: You could use whatever copying facility is provided by your shell - e.g. [copying from tmux](http://awhan.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/copy-paste-in-tmux/)... although that particular example is not really faster.

Comment: Tab completion isn't available on all platforms.  Neither cmd nor PowerShell have Git autocomplete out of the box.  Yes, you can use Git bash, but if your limited for some reason (company policy or something) and have to go through Git, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The same way you "type" *any* long command or option. Install tab completion for your shell. Git has excellent tab completion support.

You can also toggle quickly between two branches with `git checkout -`, which checks out the previous branch you were on before the last checkout.

Comment: See update. Tabbing doesn't really help much, at least it's not as quick as using the mouse in this case.

Comment: @Jason Get better at typing? There isn't any magic way of doing this that doesn't involve the keyboard or mouse.

Comment: @meagar: "that doesn't involve the keyboard or mouse" --- "Ok, Git, checkout to long-branch-name-i-want-to-checkout-without-using-my-mouse"

Answer (score 4):

Add this alias to your git config and it will search and checkout simular branch:

```
> git config --global alias.fb '!sh -c \"git branch -a | grep -v remotes | grep $1 | head -n 1 | xargs git checkout\"'
```

list of my branch:

```
> git branch
  18-notification-topic
* develop
```

usage of alias:

```
> git fb 18
Switched to branch '18-notification-topic'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/18-notification-topic'.
```

[more information on chris holts site.](http://chrisholtz.com/blog/switch-git-branch-by-partial-name/)

Comment: Works great when your branches each have a unique identifier!

Answer (score 1):

If you're in Emacs, you can use meta-/ or meta-p, and it'll often autocomplete with the most recently used autocompletion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tmux, you can use a script like:

```
sed -n "${1}p" | expand | while read line; do
        echo "$line" | tr -d \\n | tmux loadb -
done
```

Then run `git branch` through that script to cut the branch name into the paste buffer.  For example, if the above line is in a script (or bash function) named `tb`, you can simply do:

```
git branch | tb 3
```

to pick out the 3rd line of the output of git-branch, or match a regex in the branch name:

```
git branch | tb /dont/
```

to match branches that contain the text `dont`.  Then you can simply pull the text out of the paste buffer (the default key sequence would be `^b]`).

If you're not using `tmux`...my condolences.  But you might be able to get away with simply piping git-branch through `pbcopy`  (just replace the call to `tmux loadb` in the script with `pbcopy`, primarily to remove newlines that are irritating to have in the paste buffer).

Answer (score 0):

List your branches with

```
$ git branch -l
```

You want to first one:

```
$ git branch -l | head -1 | xargs git checkout
```

If you want another one, you have to add a tail -1

```
$ git branch -l | head -2 | tail -1 | xargs git checkout
```

You can also use grep to match part of the branchname

```
$ git branch -l | grep partialbranchname | xargs git checkout
```